# does ros can be loaded onto Snappy Ubuntu Core?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

working on raspbery pi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205467/does-ros-can-be-loaded-onto--snappy-ubuntu-core?/) by [nilesh thakkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21923/nilesh-thakkr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Old question, but it still comes up on Google so I'll mention that this is officially supported by Snapcraft, the tool for building .snaps for Ubuntu Core: https://docs.snapcraft.io/ros-applications/7822 .

---

Originally posted by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) with karma: 347 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2019-01-02**:
Link https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/ros-snap/ seems not available any more.

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2019-01-07**:
Thank you, I updated the link.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-07**:
@Kyle: can you say something about your experiences with snaps and ROS? What level of granularity have you used / do you believe makes the most sense? Single snap per node? Any thoughts on the filesize overhead?

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2019-01-07**:
I work at Canonical (the company behind Ubuntu) on this, so I'm biased, but I've used it quite a bit. Splitting nodes between snaps is complex since they're isolated, but snaps are an excellent way to ship/update an entire ROS product at once. Regarding size, updates are all done with deltas.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. See:

- [Ubuntu ROS apps on the way](http://www.osrfoundation.org/ubuntu-ros-apps-on-the-way/)
- [Snappy package for Robot Operating System tutorial](http://www.piware.de/2015/01/snappy-package-for-robot-operating-system-tutorial/)

It will require some manual work currently, but that should be temporary.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1